# Failed to receive SMS on Android (process is bad)

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have tried many (if not all...) **Receive SMS** examples, but it always failed before even onReceive() is called.

**The CatLog:**

```
10-26 20:05:30.990: INFO/System.out(2714): INFO: Received message
10-26 20:05:30.998: INFO/System.out(2714): INFO: Message body: Lmjgk
10-26 20:05:31.021: WARN/ActivityManager(1317): Unable to launch app org.apache.sms/10166 for broadcast Intent { act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED (has extras) }: process is bad
10-26 20:05:31.021: WARN/ActivityManager(1317): finishReceiver called but none active
```

When implemented alongside another BroadcastReceiver android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE, the later is being called and was working perfectly well while the SMS failed.

To simplify it I just created the hello example and updates to the manifest and one file for the SMS BroadcastReceiver.

**The manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.byp.sms" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".HelloActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.byp.sms.SMSReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
</manifest>
```

**The BroadcastReceiver**

```
    package com.byp.sms;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("SMSReceiver", "onReceive"); // <<=== It does not even get here....
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null
                && ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {
            Object[] pduArray = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
            Log.d("SMSReceiver", "SMSReceived " + pduArray.toString());
        }
        Log.d("SMSReceiver", "onReceive...Done");
      }
    }
```

**Hello Activity:** No changes to the generated code

```
package com.byp.sms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

It did not help that I cleaned up all related apps from the device, uninstalled it, rebooted the device, etc, etc.

Any advice or a tip will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the Receiver as static if you are registering it in the AndroidManifest file.
and if the receiver is not static then you need to register through code. please do above things it will show some positive result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can not change the signature of the onReceive() by adding static, can you help with an example?

Comment: What happen? didn't you got your ans

Comment: any process is going on this question?

Comment: Hi, a little bit late, but better late then never... thanks for your answer it was very helpful!

Comment: Accept the ans and close the question :) there will be tick mark below my ans